# Environment variables are not available with systemd

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv, gunicorn

I am deploying a flask app that is running inside virtual env

I have the systemd file as follow:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve my-page
After=network.target

[Service]
User=jb
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/jb/webjosue/my-page
Environment="PATH=/home/jb/webjosue/FlaskENV/bin"
ExecStart=/home/jb/webjosue/FlaskENV/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:my-page.sock -m 007 wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

In my main.py I have

```
settings = os.environ['APP_SETTINGS']
```

and I get this error

```
raise KeyError(key)
Sep 24 00:10:13 ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01 gunicorn[23439]: KeyError: 'settings'
```

I am guessing since I have my environment pointing to the virtualenv (FlaskENV) the other environment variables that are in my .profile are not being recognized.

Any ideas?

Comment: no, I am reading the environment variable and then assigning it to settings since I will use this variable somewhere else. But the environment variable APP_SETTINGS is never found. However, I am able to run it fine locally.

Comment: My first guess is that gunicorn is running as a different user and as such your sessions environment variables aren't available.

Comment: You can just put the Environment variables in the systemd service file.

Answer (score 1):

As @Joe Doherty said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39671254/environment-variables-are-not-available-with-systemd#comment67037659_39671254), you can use `Environment` directive in `Service` section to add environment variables, more [information](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-environment-variables-in-systemd-units.html). For instance:

```
[Service]
Environment="PATH=/xx/yy/zz/venv/bin"
Environment="FLASK_ENV=development"
Environment="APP_SETTINGS=config.DevelopmentConfig"
```

I was using virtualenv so `/xx/yy/zz/venv/bin` is the path of virtualenv folder.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow `Environment="FLASK_ENV=development"` with quotes wasn't working

```
Environment=FLASK_ENV=development
```

with no quotes was working just fine